# Side by Side Horizontal Boxplots Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I'm trying to plot side-by-side horizontal boxplots in Pandas. Any idea why I get the following error?

[image: Error]

Comment: Please do not share images of code and/or errors. Instead, copy and paste them here. You should do this since it is impossible to debug screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ax[0]` and `ax[1]` not `ax[0][0]` and `ax[0][1]`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "column1" : ["ABC", "DEF"],
    "column2" : [4,1],
    "column3" : [1,4],
}) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)

df.plot("column1", "column2", kind="bar", ax=ax[0])
df.plot("column1", "column3", kind="bar", ax=ax[1])
```

Output:
[image: Axes bar plot]